# I m not able to find any reference to create IAM for Stop Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-opsworks

Is there any way by which I can write a IAM policy so that I can restrict users to "stop all instances" in opsworks at once but can allow them to stop one at a time.

I searched through but cannot find any reference to make that possible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cleared with AWS guys, they have no such feature which would help here to **StopAllInstances** in OpsWorks.